# How do I create a circuit which has cyclical output?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier

I am thinking about using some sort of hysteresis comparator circuit to pull of this particular output.[image: Graph]

However it is particularly difficult to see what I could do to produce this circuit.

Edit: The y axis is current, the x axis voltage

Comment: How about two diodes connected anode to cathode so the overall circuit (a new two terminal device) conducts in both directions?

Comment: Just a career tip: always always always put labels on your axes and double check them.

Comment: How would i then produce the sloped inner parts?

Comment: What about a hysteresis compartor in series with an integrator?

Comment: What do you mean by "this particular output"? Is the current the input and the voltage the output, or vice versa, or neither? Your graph shows multiple possible outputs for each possible input; which output do you want under what circumstances?

Comment: You can't control the current and the voltage of an output separately at the same time. You have to pick one.

Comment: a little context about what you are actually trying to do would not do any harm here either. This is a bit abstract as it strands.

Comment: another "career tip" : when asking a question, put yourselves in the position of someone who knows NOTHING about your problem or application, and ask yourself if you are asking in the clearest and most efficient way possible. In general this will make people more sympathetic to your question (and you), as it shows that you respect their time. Also, the process of clarifying the question may already suggest possible solutions in your own mind. Communication is everything.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that voltage is the input and current is the output you need. The following can work if you are ok to approximating the curves to straight lines.

[image]

The opamps and comparators used need to have a very low offset for this to meet your requirements. Also another limitation could come from the fact that if VIN is noisy, you'll need hysteresis in the comparator and that can also create some discontinuity in the VIN Iout relationship. Around VIN=0 is where it gets tricky with this scheme for these reasons.